# Python: updating reference values

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, reference, mutability

The following works how I believe it should:

```
dictionary = {'k1': {'a': 'b'}, 'k2': [0, 1]}  
pointer = dictionary['k1']  
print pointer  
>>> {'a': 'b'}  
pointer.update({'a': 'c'})  
print dictionary  
>>> {'k1': {'a': 'c'}, 'k2': [0, 1]}
```

The following frustrates me:

```
pointer = dictionary['k2']
print pointer
>>> [0, 1]
pointer.update([2, 3])
>>> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

**I am aware list has no update function** and understand I could do something like:

```
pointer[0] = 2
```

... but I would like a more universal option to update a reference value, so the object still belongs to the dictionary but the value has changed.

The reason for this being I have a nested dictionary that looks something like:

```
dictionary['key']['key']['key']['key']
```

My question is not aimed around if list has an update function - rather **I'm asking if there's a cleaner way to reference and change a value inside of a deeply nested dictionary** so it would be nicer on the eyes to store that in a reference value rather than type it all out every time I want to assign something to it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed syntax in first example
EDIT2: Let me be clear: I'm aware list does not have an `update` function, rather I'm asking about a universal reference value update
EDIT3: simplified question

Comment: Read the error message. That is all there is to it. (There are **no** variable references in Python, only mutable objects.)

Comment: None of this has *anything* to do with the fact that your values live in a dictionary. If these were globals (`k1 = {...}` and `k2 = [...]`) the output would be exactly the same. You are just referencing the objects differently.

Comment: If you want to be able to call the same methods, you should use the same data types.  What you say at the end of your question suggests your actual issue is rather different from what you describe.  Can you say what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Also note that if you have a dict inside a dict inside a dict and you want to alter the value associated with some key in the innermost dict, you only need a reference to the innermost dict and the key, the outer dicts are entirely unfazed by what you might be doing inside that dict.

Comment: You cannot have a 'universal update feature' when you mix types. Stick to one type instead!

Comment: The thing is, lists have order. What does `.update()` mean in that case? What is updated? Is anything to be removed? Replaced? Inserted? Where is it to be inserted? These are very different operations!

Comment: I'm unclear about what you want, since your hypothetical universal update function still needs different parameters depending on whether you're on a leaf node or not. Since you need different parameters, a different statement doesn't seem like an onerous requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference value"?  Not only is there no universal update, there is no universal notion of a "reference value".  There are just individual types that support whatever operations they support.  Even if dict and list share some operations (and they do), that wouldn't make them universal, since they might not be supported by other types (including user-defined classes).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. My question is not aimed around if list has an update function - rather I'm asking if there's a cleaner way to reference and change a value inside of a deeply nested dictionary

Comment: @praterade: Then maybe you should edit your question to focus more directly on what you actually want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing. References point at objects, not at places inside objects. Period. This is a fundamental part of the Python object model.

You can, if you are so inclined, write a class that represents such a location:

```
class AttributeReference:
    def __init__(self, obj, attr):
        self.obj = obj
        self.attr = attr

    def set(self, value):
        setattr(self.obj, self.attr, value)

    # add get() and del() and other methods to your heart's content 


class ElementReference:
    def __init__(self, obj, key):
        self.obj = obj
        self.key = key

    def set(self, value):
        self.obj[self.key] = value

    # add get() and del() and other methods to your heart's content
```

Then you can use such an object instead of a Python reference.
However, it's rather unwieldy to use, so the bar for using it is rather higher.
On the bright side, the depth of nesting is completely irrelevant. If you want a "reference" to `dictionary['k1']['k2']['k3']['k4']`, this will do: `ElementReference(dictionary['k1']['k2']['k3'], 'k4')`.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and putting it so politely.

Answer (score 3):

As is evident from the error message, a `list` doesn't have an `update` method. That doesn't mean you can't change its contents, you just need to do it differently.

```
pointer[:] = [2, 3]
```

You *can* make a universal update function but I'm not sure how useful it will be.

```
def update(pointer, values):
    if isinstance(pointer, list):
        pointer[:] = values
    else:
        pointer.update(dict(values))
```

**Edit:** it appears you really only are interested in updating leaf nodes, so I don't understand why the following wasn't sufficient. As long as `pointer` is set to a mutable object you can change that object and it will also change in the original dictionary. The only thing you *can't* do is reassign it directly, because that reassigns *the reference* and breaks the connection to the dictionary.

```
pointer = dictionary['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']
# pointer = [2, 3]   # doesn't work
pointer[:] = [2, 3]  # works
print dictionary['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']
```

Comment: The question shows he already knows he can do it differently.  What he wants is to somehow do it the same way as for a dict.

Comment: @BrenBarn that wasn't obvious when I wrote the answer.

Comment: "For lists and dicts" is a far cry from "universal", and unless the caller correctly supplies values for all keys it also does different things for those two types.

Comment: @delnan I know, I'm still actually trying to figure out exactly what they're trying to accomplish. My code has a bug too, `dict(list)` doesn't do what I thought it did.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding concerning pointers and specifically how variables are labelled and accessed in Python.

To start at the beginning, a "pointer" in lower level languages like C is simply an integer that contains a memory address. Through special syntax, `*pointer`, you can indicate that you want to access the data at the memory location rather than the integer representing the location. Why would you want to operate on the integer? Read up on pointer arithmetic, the explanation goes beyond the scope of this answer.

Many languages, Python included, assume that you never need to operate on the pointers directly, so while a Python variable name like your variable called `pointer` has a memory address associated with it (I won't go into stack vs heap here, again, beyond the scope), Python abstracts that away from you as a developer. In Python, using a variable name, you will always access the data directly.

As you are accessing the data directly, you must treat that data as the correct type. If you don't, you encounter errors like the one you saw. You could "update" the pointer, but this would simply be changing the memory location it points at, not changing the data at the location, and therefore would not be reflected in `dictionary`.

To clear up some of the confusion, consider variable names in Python to be "labels" (the documentation uses this term I believe). 2 labels may point at the same piece of data that has functions and attributes, but the labels themselves are not objects with functions and attributes.

Other people have already suggested specific solutions for your list vs dict example. I hope this explains the "why" of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure if I totally understand your question, but here are two approaches.  Suppose you have a dict like this:

```
d = {'level1': {'level2': {'level3': {'level4': [1, 2, 3]}}}}
```

`d['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']` gives you a reference to the innermost list.  If you store that, you can do whatever you want with it:

```
innerValue = d['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']
innerValue.append(4)

>>> d
{'level1': {'level2': {'level3': {'level4': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}}}
```

As others have noted in comments, though, what you are modifying here is the *list*.  The list does not "know" that it is inside a dictionary.  What you can do to that list is the same as what you can do to any other list.  If it were not a list but some other kind of object, the same applies: what you can do to it when it's inside a dict is the same as what you can do to it anywhere else.  If you want to update the object in-place, the dict will not be notified of that.  So there's no way to have a "universal" method of updating that is based on the fact that the object in inside a dict, because object's don't know whether they're inside dicts or not.

An alternative is to store a reference to the dict containing the element you want to modify.  Then you can change its value using the normal dict operations:

```
innerDict = d['level1']['level2']['level3']
innerDict['level4'] = "Some other value"

>>> d
{'level1': {'level2': {'level3': {'level4': 'Some other value'}}}}
```

This method is "universal" in the sense that it does not depend on what kind of value is stored in that inner dict.  What's happening there is you are updating that inner dict so its value points at a new object.  Note, though, that this creates a new object, so it doesn't modify the original list in-place (and can even, as in my example, change what type of value it is).  It does modify the inner dict in-place (by assigning a new value to one of its keys).

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve, but these are two ways to store some sort of reference to something in a deeply nested dict, and then mess with it.

Comment: Yes this along the lines of what I'm asking. Basically - is there any way to change the type of an object and still have it contained in the dictionary. It sounds like the answer is no unless you replace the object completely.